# Autocreating instances of class in C#

Tags: c#, class

I need help with auto creating instances of class. Creating instances Is easy

```
public class human
{

}

human h1=new human ();
```

Is there a way how to name instances with field or text from textbox? something like

```
human h[1] =new human();
```

or

```
human "textbox1.text" =new human;
```

I already read some post about reflection, but i do not get it :-(
do you have some code that can help?

Comment: Just create an array or a list of `Human`? Something like `var people = new List<Human>();`And then `people.Add(new Human(...))`?

Comment: Please tell us what kind of problem you're trying to solve where this could be the solution, it's very hard to envision a scenario where this would be helpful. Why doesn't "h1" work for you as a variable name?

Comment: If it's just a text box then a `List<string>` should be adequate. A text box can only hold strings so a class seems a waste of time

Comment: I think OP wants to create a new instance of `Human` and reference that instance by a dynamic name. Si of `textbox.text` equals `1`, he gets `h[1] = new Human()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by creating a string property on `Human` called (for example) `Name`.

```
public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Human(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

You can set this property from the constructor (this is the method which executes when you instantiate an instance of the object).

```
var human = new Human(textBox1.Text);
```

You can create a map of names (if you want to access instances of the class by name) with a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` object.

```
var humans = new Dictionary<string, Human>();

// add by name.
humans.Add(textBox1.Text, new Human(textBox1.Text));

// retrieve by name.
var human = humans[textBox1.Text];
```

Comment: In your `Dictionary` you probably wanted to write `new Human(textBox1.Text)` instead of the empty constructor `new Human()`

Comment: Thankyou really much, it helped much :-)

Comment: I tryied your code but exception "The name 'human' does not exist in the current context"  exception occuredreferring to part:

`human = new Human(textBox1.Text);`

what is wrong?

Comment: You need to prefix it with "var " I'll update the answer.